# CSS media queries by div width or height

Tags: css, media-queries, container-queries

Is it possible, to specific CSS styles by some DIV width or height?

Something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
```

Comment: I can't think of a good reason on why it would be needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery.

```
function change_size(){
   var window_height = $(window).height();
   var div_height = $("#your_id").height();
   if(window_height < div_height){
          $("#your_id").css({marginTop: "20px", height: "20px"});  //for example
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   change_size();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
   change_size();
});
```

Comment: Ok and what about loading other CSS files, based on DIV size? Will it change, when I apply it on resize event?

Comment: you mean when you resize the window?

Comment: yes on window resize

Comment: I edited the answer. See it again.

Comment: yes I mean this but I want to include whole CSS file... Will it work?

Comment: why not? Just be careful about the id of your div.

Comment: did it work for you?